# How to retrieve the top N accounts for an SPL token by quantity?

Tags: solana

Suppose I have an SPL token $TOKEN.

Let's say that 100 different accounts hold $TOKEN in associated token accounts. They hold different quantities of the token. For example, the distribution may look like this:

> - Account 00...01 holds 1 $TOKEN
> - Account 00...02 holds 2 $TOKEN
> - ...
> - Account 00...99 holds 99 $TOKEN

I want to know who the top N token holders are by $TOKEN quantity. For example, if N = 3, I want to return these accounts in this order:

> - Account 00...99
> - Account 00...98
> - Account 00...97

Is there a way to easily retrieve this information?

Comment: Do you mean in code? Coz Solana explorer already gives you this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This endpoint will return the 20 largest token accounts for the specified mint: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenlargestaccounts